# Flask read in frame from diffrent process

Tags: python, flask, webserver

I have a programm, that starts many processes and gets videoframes from one of them. The frames are in a multiprocessing queue and I can access them in the main program at any time.

Now I want to implement a flask webserver, that runs as a seperate process, started by the main process.

The server currently looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response

class FlaskAppWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, app, **configs):
        self.app = app
        self.configs(**configs)
        self.frame = None

    def configs(self, **configs):
        for config, value in configs:
            self.app.config[config.upper()] = value

    def add_endpoint(self, endpoint=None, endpoint_name=None, handler=None, methods=['GET'], *args, **kwargs):
        self.app.add_url_rule(endpoint, endpoint_name, handler, methods=methods, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def run(self, **kwargs):
        self.app.run(**kwargs)

    def index():
        return render_template('index.html')

    def gen(self):
        while True:
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + self.frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
            
    def video_feed(self):
        return Response(self.gen(),
                        mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

def run_webserver():
    flask_app = Flask(__name__)
    app = FlaskAppWrapper(flask_app)

    app.add_endpoint('/index', 'index', app.index, methods=['GET'])
    app.add_endpoint('/video_feed', 'video_feed', app.video_feed, methods=['GET'])


    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port='5000', debug=True)
```

In theory I only need to apply the new frame to the `self.frame` value and it should work. But I dont know how to update the `self.frame`, because if the app runs it blocks the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use a seperate thread to read framse from the multiprocessing queue and update self.frame

```
import threading
from queue import Queue
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response

class FlaskAppWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, app, **configs):
        self.app = app
        self.configs(**configs)
        self.frame = None
        self.frame_queue = Queue()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self._update_frame)
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

    def configs(self, **configs):
        for config, value in configs:
            self.app.config[config.upper()] = value

    def add_endpoint(self, endpoint=None, endpoint_name=None, handler=None, methods=['GET'], *args, **kwargs):
        self.app.add_url_rule(endpoint, endpoint_name, handler, methods=methods, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def run(self, **kwargs):
        self.app.run(**kwargs)

    def index(self):
        return render_template('index.html')

    def gen(self):
        while True:
            frame = self.frame_queue.get()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
            
    def video_feed(self):
        return Response(self.gen(),
                        mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

    def _update_frame(self):
        while True:
            frame = self.get_frame_from_queue()
            self.frame = frame

    def get_frame_from_queue(self):
        # logic for getting a frame from the multiprocessing queue here
        return frame

def run_webserver():
    flask_app = Flask(__name__)
    app = FlaskAppWrapper(flask_app)

    app.add_endpoint('/index', 'index', app.index, methods=['GET'])
    app.add_endpoint('/video_feed', 'video_feed', app.video_feed, methods=['GET'])

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='5000', debug=True)
```

Comment: Ok, I will try that. But can the thread change the self.frame variable of the FlaskWrapper instance? For me it would seem that the Thread would alse neet to have some kind of shared variable, or am I wrong?